# Ansible Inventory: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)\r\n/bin/sh

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I am learninng Jenkins, I am build a remote host container and try to connect to it via Ansible. However, when I run the command `ansible -i hosts -m ping test1`, I get the error as below, I try to search and work around for some solutions, but no hope.

jenkins@3118b45582bc:~/ansible$ ansible -i hosts -m ping test1

test1 | FAILED! => {
"changed": false,
"module_stderr": "Shared connection to remote_host closed.\r\n",
"module_stdout": "bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)\r\n/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)\r\n/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)\r\n/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)\r\n/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory\r\n",
"msg": "The module failed to execute correctly, you probably need to set the interpreter.\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
"rc": 127
}

jenkins@3118b45582bc:~/ansible$ cat hosts

[all:vars]

ansible_connection = ssh

[test]
test1 ansible_host=remote_host ansible_user=remote_user ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/var/jenkins_home/ansible/remote-key

jenkins@3118b45582bc:~/ansible$ ping remote_host

PING remote_host (172.18.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from remote-host.jenkins-data_net (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.166 ms
64 bytes from remote-host.jenkins-data_net (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.289 ms
64 bytes from remote-host.jenkins-data_net (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.358 ms
^C
--- remote_host ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 7ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.166/0.271/0.358/0.079 ms

Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks and Regards,
--William

Comment: `/usr/bin/python: No such file or directory` Do you have python installed on `test1`? If yes, is it properly symlinked to an instance of `python3`?

Comment: You are also skating on thin ice trying to name hosts in a [non-RFC 1123](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1123#section-2) way, assuming you didn't just mangle that text for the purposes of posting here

Comment: Hi, 

I installed python on my hosts already


lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     7 Mar 18 12:30 python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     9 Mar 18 12:30 python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  7144 Oct 14 10:46 python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     9 Mar 20 15:08 python3 -> python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 11328 Nov 16 11:59 python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 11328 Nov 16 11:59 python3.6m


the remote_host use centos7, I don;t know the root cause, whethere  I miss python installation on this image?, It seems the issue related to /bin/sh and #!/bin/sh when I run the Dockerfile.

Comment: Please don't shove a lot of preformatted text into the comments; [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66768023/edit) to include those details

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix can be just adding the path to python 3 (`ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3`) in your inventory file (hosts), just like:

```
test1 ansible_host=remote_host ansible_user=remote_user ansible_private_key_file=/var/jenkins_home/ansible/remote-key ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```